# What would be the simplest method to copy a row using Google App script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sourceSheet where one row has been highlighted.

I wish to copy the entire row to destinationSheet.

OK this is what I have so far:

function CopyActiveRow(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sourceSheet=ss.getSheetByName("get_copy");
var targetSheet=ss.getSheetByName("test_copy");

var myrow=sourceSheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();

sourceSheet.getRange(myrow.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange('A2:k2')));

}

I'm stuck (and must be missing something :)

What would be the simplest way to copy a (selected/active) row?

Comment: Welcome to SO!!!. I would suggest to do some research (may be documentation) on your own. If you get stuck in a particular issue come back with your question, with as much information possible, including code snippet that you tried.

Comment: Sure, I've just updated my question with my current code. Perhaps you'd be kind enough to point me in the right direction, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `copyTo`.

`sourceRange.copyTo(destinationRange);`

**REFERENCES**

[copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))